# Pagination with AJAX in Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, pagination

I have an account page where objects saved in a database by the user are displayed as a list.

I use `Pagination` to navigate through the different objects. Everything is working as it should.

But now I would like to use AJAX on top of it. I already use it to save and delete objects from the list but this case is a lot trickier.... or not.

My list is loaded to a page which url contains the user_id to filter the objects.

What I would like to do, but maybe it's not the best solution, it's to bound the button I have in the nav bar to acces the account and the button at the bottom of the page that switches pagination.

My AJAX:

```
$(".next-button").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var page_n = $(this).attr('href');      
    url = '/register/pagination'
    console.log(page_n);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url, 
        data : {               
            'page_n' : page_n, 
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    },
    error: function () {}
});  
});
```

My views.py:

```
def account(request, user_id):

    if request.method=='POST':        
        data['success'] = True
        return JsonResponse(data)

    else:              
        sub_list = SavedProduct.objects.filter(username = user_id)
        paginator = Paginator(sub_list, 5)
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        saved_list = paginator.get_page(page_number) 

        context = {
            'saved_list': saved_list,              
        }
        return render(request, 'account/account.html', context)
```

My urls:

```
app_name = 'register'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:user_id>/', views.account, name='account'),
    path('delete/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('pagination', views.account, name='pagination'), 
    ]
```

My HTML:

```
{% if saved_list.has_next %}
        <span><a class='next-button' href="?page={{ saved_list.next_page_number }}"> {% csrf_token %} next</a></span>
        {% endif %}
```